# How do I find the value of DISPLAY on a linux terminal

Tags: linux

Suppose I did an `export DISPLAY=:1` in an X forwarded ssh session. Now I want to reset it back to its original value so that when I launch X apps they show up on my screen and not on `:1`. Is there any way to find what it was and set it to that ? Or does the value get lost irrevocably once it is overwritten ?

I don't want to have to restart ssh session just because I changed the value of `DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save it into another variable first:

```
export DISPLAY_BACKUP=$DISPLAY
export DISPLAY=:1
```

To restore it back, do:

```
export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY_BACKUP
```

In case the `DISPLAY` variable was not saved, you can use the following code snippet (found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine)) to try to get its original value:

```
netstat -lnt | awk '
sub(/.*:/,"",$4) && $4 >= 6000 && $4 < 6100 {
    print ($1 == "tcp6" ? "ip6-localhost" : "localhost:") ($4 - 6000)
}'
```

Remote displays correspond to open TCP ports above 6000; accessing display number N on machine M is done by connecting to TCP port 6000+N on machine M.

Comment: Actually, I am asking for the case where I did not save it. Is it possible to restore the display then ? I mean there must be *some* way to find out what the *real* display value is !

Comment: @AnkurVj I would say it is not possible to do that (unless you can guess the old value). Of course you can always restart the SSH connection.

Comment: @AnkurVj Probably the display value was something like `localhost:10.0`. But that will depend on whether other X11 sessions are active.

Comment: okay, that seems more effort than restarting ssh session. Although seems a legit hack to find out what I am looking for. Thanks !